# Why two symbols for the Golden Ratio?

Tags: math-history

Why is it that both
$\phi$
and
$\tau$
are used to designate the Golden Ratio
$\frac{1+\sqrt5}2?$

Comment: I have never heard of $\tau$ denoting the Golden Ratio. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I too have only seen $\phi$ used for this

Comment: It is just a symbol, who cares? I can use the symbol $U:=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$.

Comment: What is $\tau$ ? Is it the reciprocal of $\phi$ ?

Comment: In some contexts, I have seen $\tau = 2 \pi$

Comment: I  saw the $\tau\quad$ version in a discussion of the Binet closed-form formula for a Fibonacci number (based upon its index).

Comment: Use of tau: *Introduction to Geometry* by H.S.M. Coxeter.  ?Perhaps also in Martin Gardner's "Mathematical Games" column in *Scientific American* when he devoted the whole column to that book when it was newly published.

Comment: I saw $\tau$ yesterday in Conway and Guy _The Book of Numbers_.  They did not mention $\varphi$ or $\phi$.

Comment: I guess I shall have to get used to multiple nicknames: Some who know me address me as "Loser" and others as "Mr. Wonderful."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Golden Ratio* or *Golden Cut* is the number
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
which is usually denoted by phi ($\phi$ or $\varphi$), but also sometimes by tau ($\tau$).

**Why $\phi$** :  [Phidias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phidias) (Greek: Φειδίας) was a Greek sculptor, painter, and architect. So $\phi$ is the first letter of his name.

> The symbol $\phi$ ("phi") was apparently first used by Mark Barr at the beginning of the 20th century in commemoration of the Greek sculptor Phidias (ca. 490-430 BC), who a number of art historians claim made extensive use of the golden ratio in his works (Livio 2002, pp. 5-6).

**Why $\tau$** : The golden ratio or golden cut is sometimes named after the greek verb τομή, meaning "to cut", so again the first letter is taken: $\tau$.

**Source:** [The Golden Ratio: The Story of Phi, the World's Most Astonishing Number](https://books.google.be/books?id=w9dmPwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Mario Livio; [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html)

Comment: \ Thank you. Could Mr. Livio have been pulling our legs? Given the constant's intimate relation to the (*F*)ibonacci series, my choice has to be $\phi.$